# Why does Google provide public hosting of popular JavaScript formats?

Tags: economics

Does Google track my coding habits to show Google ads in their search if i use any their hosted JavaScript framework?

...Or is there some other reason for them to host these? What *is* the benefit to them from hosting these frameworks?

Comment: Is your question "can they" or "do they"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google wants the web to be as rich as possible, the more apps and sites, the more possible ad revenue for them.

No, they cannot track you by the frameworks, they are fetched once across all sites that use that url and then cached on the client.  If say 20 sites all references a js file hosted on google, the user only gets it once.  Hosting your own...if it's an intranet app, yes do that, if not then reference google, lower your load times a bit most likely.

Also, google has peering agreements, bandwidth is very, very cheap for them.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about the war between Microsoft and Google. Google wants web applications to replace desktop ones.